# PostgreSQL text Array Query Optimisation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write an SQL query in Postgres that queries the  [IMDB dataset](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/) and looks for a movie where two actors supplied have featured in. The movies actors/actresses  have featured in is in an array as a field (known_for_titles) in the names table.

I originally tried unnesting the arrays and then doing an intersection for both actors and then the result of this query is used to fetch the name of the movie from the titles Table

The names table looks like this

```
  nconst   |  primary_name   |              known_for_titles              
-----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------
 nm0000001 | Fred Astaire    | {tt0072308,tt0053137,tt0043044,tt0050419}
 nm0000002 | Lauren Bacall   | {tt0038355,tt0117057,tt0037382,tt0071877}
```

The Titles table looks like this

```
 tconst   | title_type |         primary_title         |  genres  
-----------+------------+-------------------------------+----------
 tt5165760 | tvEpisode  | Episode dated 3 November 2015 | {News}
 tt5165764 | tvEpisode  | Episode dated 4 November 2015 | {News}
 tt5165776 | movie      | Cuando den las Tres           | {Drama}
 tt5165778 | tvEpisode  | Episode dated 9 November 2015 | {News}
```

The names_to_titles table looks like this

```
id_names  | id_titles 
-----------+-----------
 nm0000001 | tt0072308
 nm0000001 | tt0053137
```

This is what my query currently looks like

```
SELECT DISTINCT primary_title 
from titles 
where tconst = (SELECT unnest(known_for_titles) 
                FROM names 
                where primary_name='Jennifer Aniston' 
                INTERSECT (SELECT unnest(known_for_titles) 
                           from names 
                           where primary_name='Matiki Anoff')
                );
```

It got me a valid output in 6 seconds, but I think there should be a more efficient way to do this that should fetch me the result which is the movie or show that two actors supplied (in my case Jennifer Aniston and Matiki Anoff) have both been in.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this one to be faster:

```
select *
from titles t
where exists (select * 
              from names n1
              where n1.primary_name = 'Jennifer Aniston' 
                and t.tconst = any(n1.known_for_titles))
  and exists (select * 
              from names n2
              where n2.primary_name = 'Matiki Anoff'
                and t.tconst = any(n2.known_for_titles));
```

An index on `names(primary_name)` and a GIN index on `names(known_for_titles)` would probably help.